# Why can't I read from a file?

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to read few bytes from a file and then print them to screen, but the `read()` function keeps returning -1 for some reason.

Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<sys/types.h> 
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdlib.h> 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    char buff[100];

    int file_desc=open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (file_desc<0) {
        printf("Error opening the file.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("File was successfully opened with file descriptor %d.\n", file_desc);


    int ret_code=read(argv[1],buff,20);
    if (ret_code==-1) {
        printf("Error reading the file.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
        printf("%c ",buff[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The output for this is:

```
File was successfully opened with file descriptor 3.
Error reading the file.
```

The file I'm trying to read from is definitely bigger than 20 bytes.
What could be the problem here?

Comment: Why use `read` family instead of `fread`?

Comment: When a system call fails, you should check [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) to see what went wrong. Use [`strerror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) to get a printable string from the error, or use [`perror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) to print the message directly.

Comment: @v3ga, what's wrong with read()?

Comment: @so.very.tired There's nothing wrong with `read` etc., but you have to remember that on POSIX systems (like Linux or Mac OSX) these are very low level system calls, i.e. they are calls into the kernel, and don't have any buffering or other "fancy" things.

Comment: OK, thanks for the tip @Joachim Pileborg, I'll remember that. but as a matter of fact, since I'm writing really tiny program for a class exercise, it's good enough for now.

Comment: It's easier to work with fread family unless you __want__ to do low-level system calls. Try them out. It's the best choice for class exercises unless it's an OS class

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, what about if this whole above code was inside another function that I have written foo(), and inside it - a system call has failed; should I just return -1 to main() or should I use perror() from **inside** foo()?

Comment: because I recall that it is not considered as good programming to print error massages to stdout from inside functions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the parameters for [`read`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), the first parameter should be the open file descriptor, not the file name;

```
int ret_code=read(file_desc,buff,20);
```

...should work better.

Comment: wow, so many question on this site, from people not taking 2 seconds to read a function prototype. smh...

Comment: OMG. my bad, I **did** actually read the function prototype, but didn't notice it...
Thanks.